# How can I replace a child class in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, extends

I have a child class like this:

```
class Child1 extends Parent {
    public function theFunction () {
        does some stuff...
    }
}
```

I want to either to replace `theFunction()` or the entire class `Child1` with a new child class `Child2`.

This doesn't work:

```
class Child2 extends Child1{
    public function theFunction () {
        does some stuff...
    }
}
```

The Parent and Child1 classes are in a Wordpress plugin, so I can't modify those parts without changing the core files.  Which I don't want to do.

How can I do this?

Comment: How it doesn't work? How do you call class methods?

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander Elgin is right.

The login for inheritance in the question should work. Example:

```
<?php

class Parent1 {
}

class Child1 extends Parent1 {
    public function theFunction () {
        return 'Child1';
    }
}

class Child2 extends Child1{
    public function theFunction () {
        return 'Child2';
    }
}

$child1 = new Child1();
echo "child1 call: '{$child1->theFunction()}' \n";

$child2 = new Child2();
echo "child2 call: '{$child2->theFunction()}' \n";
?>
```

demo: https://eval.in/481992